# How can I build an LSTM network for two dimensional data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I see that LSTM in Keras accepts (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim) as the input shape. But I am wondering if there is an easy way to expand these to 4 dimensions?
For example, how can we apply lstm to the moving-MNIST dataset that we have images of size 64 by 64?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CNN model to extract features of your images before feeding them into your LSTM.

```
# define CNN model
cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(...))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(...))
cnn.add(Flatten())

# define LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn, ...))
model.add(LSTM(..))
model.add(Dense(...))
```

Comment: If you need a resource explaining why we use a `TimeDistributed` wrapping layer: https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/

Comment: @AnnaKrogager, Isn't there a way that I do not have to use convolution? basically, I want a network where I have one LSTM for each location.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean but maybe you could use a TimeDistributed LSTM? This will apply an LSTM to each temporal slice of your data (along axis 1). Just make sure that you have permuted your axes in the right way first. However, this wouldn't make much sense for image data.